# Can't update or destroy embedded object on mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid

i'm trying to update an embedded object on mongoid and terminal says true, but the change is not persisted on database.

This is the command

```
a = Post.first
b = Category.last
a.category = b
b.save <-- return true but no persist on db
```

When I try to change one single value of the embedded object says RuntimeError: can't modify frozen BSON::Document.

```
a.category.name = "test" <-- return RuntimeError: can't modify frozen BSON::Document.
```

Any ideas? I'm using mongoid 4.0

Post:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :intro, type: String
  field :content, type: String

  embeds_one :category
```

Category:

```
class Category  
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
```

Regards,

Comment: Added post and category models to first post. What do you refer to save parent? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
a = Post.first
b = Category.last
a.category = b
b.save <-- return true but no persist on db
```

You should be saving variable `a` instead of `b`, like this:

```
a.category = b
a.save #this would save the category id to post.
```

and NOW,

```
a.category.name = "test"
```

would work.